# Elantech multitouch breaks after sleep and unknown events

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, elantech, scrolling

EDIT: I previously thought this was related to mouse, but I have been experiencing these issues without a mouse plugged-in during the past weeks. I therefore rewrote the description.

The two-finger scrolling on my UX31 works just fine, but sometimes it stops working, the cause is unknown. Multitouch also breaks whenever I go in sleep mode.

Logging out and back in fixes the issue, till it happens again (sleep, or the unknown source)

Does this sound familiar to anyone here?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a driver problem. I have a similar kind of problem with my samsung SS7. What i did was to downgrade the driver to the earlier version. Somehow, Windows 7 installed an elan-tech driver version when I am supposed to be using Samsung's version.

My issue was whenever my notebook starts from hibernation mode, though it's stated that touchpad is working and active, I cant seem to use it.